# awk if-greater-than and replacement under condition

Tags: if-statement, replace, awk

I have following data

```
  ......
  6       4       4      17     154      93     309       0   11930
  7       3       2     233     311       0   11936   11932  111874
  8       3       1      15       0   11938   11943  211004   11449
  9       3       2      55     102       0   11932   11941  111883
 10       3       2     197     231       0   11925   11921  111849
 11       3       2     160     777       0   11934   11928  111875
 ......
```

I hope to replace any values greater than 5000 to 0, from column 4 to column 9. How can I do this work with awk?

Comment: Do you need to retain the spacing, or is a single space between fields ok?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I hope to keep same spacing. This is %7d formated for each columns. But I also hope to learn about single space too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print with lots of spaces like the input, something like this:

```
awk '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++)if($i>5000)$i=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%7d",$i;printf"\n"}' file
```

**Output**

```
      6      4      4     17    154     93    309      0      0
      7      3      2    233    311      0      0      0      0
      8      3      1     15      0      0      0      0      0
      9      3      2     55    102      0      0      0      0
     10      3      2    197    231      0      0      0      0
     11      3      2    160    777      0      0      0      0
```

For `scrunched up together` (TM) output, you can use this:

```
awk '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++)if($i>5000)$i=0}1' file
6 4 4 17 154 93 309 0 0
7 3 2 233 311 0 0 0 0
8 3 1 15 0 0 0 0 0
9 3 2 55 102 0 0 0 0
10 3 2 197 231 0 0 0 0
11 3 2 160 777 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach (requires `gawk4+`):

```
{
    patsplit($0, a, "[0-9]+", s)
    printf s[0]
    for (i=1; i<=length(a); i++){
        if(i>4 && a[i]>5000) {
            l=length(a[i])
            a[i]=0
        }
        else l=0
        printf "%"l"s%s", a[i], s[i]
    }
    printf "\n"
}
```

It is more flexible when the spacing would vary, as opposed to the example data. It might also be faster than the accepted answer, in case the number of fields is way bigger than 9.